# Is it possible to analyze windows message queue from a crash dump?

Tags: windows, debugging, message-queue, windbg

My application once crashed because of windows message queue limit was exceeded. This bug is very hard to reproduce. How do I analyze windows message queue contents from a crash dump?

Comment: If you already know that's the problem then just induce it.  Call PostMessage() in a loop until it returns FALSE.  Should be after about 10,000 calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A user-mode dump file does not contain message queue contents. You can obtain it from a kernel dump, though, if that is an option. LiveKD can generate a kernel dump without requiring rebooting the system in debug mode and attaching a real kernel debugger.

Comment: Ok, and how can I analyze it from a kernel dump?

Comment: The general process is described here: http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2009/11/jumping-the-queues/